# google spreadsheet export into json file, how to format?

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

I am following the tutorials that can help extract my google spreadsheet to a json file http://blog.pamelafox.org/2013/06/exporting-google-spreadsheet-as-json.html . But I have a list of object in some of the google spreadsheet cell. My one of my spreadsheet is like this: [screenshot http://www.tianyuwu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Screen-Shot-2014-09-22-at-11.46.00-PM.png](http://www.tianyuwu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Screen-Shot-2014-09-22-at-11.46.00-PM.png).

What I expert is to make the json file like this.

```
{
        "features": "*articles\n*archive\n*video\n*search\n*social",
        "data": "*news feeds\n*oroeco team",
        "content": "* blog posts\n* analysis\n* screen shots",

    }
```

But what I expect is like this

```
  {
            "features": "articles","archive","video", "search", "social",
            "data": "news feeds","oroeco team",
            "content": "* blog posts","analysis", "screen shots",

        }
```

What is the most efficient way to convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JavaScript, try this:

```
json_original = {
    "features" : "*articles\n*archive\n*video\n*search\n*social",
    "data" : "*news feeds\n*oroeco team",
    "content" : "* blog posts\n* analysis\n* screen shots",
}

json_formated = {}
for (var p in json_original) {
    json_formated[p] = json_original[p].replace('\n', '').split('*').map(function(x) { return x.trim(); }).filter(function(x) {return x != ''; });
}
```